# What Intel modality use GDB?

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb

I can assign Intel syntax to GDB, but there are differentes between NASM and MASM as:

```
NASM: mov eax,[variable]
MASM: mov eax,variable
```

What "modality" use GDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's closer to `masm`, since it does not use brackets around the address. Apparently the difference is indicated by the presence of a segment prefix:

```
   0x8048098 <_start>:          mov    eax,0x1
   0x804809d <_start+5>:        mov    eax,ds:0x1
```

(The first one loads immediate `1`, the second loads from memory address `1`)

`gdb` adds a size specifier when necessary, such as: `add    BYTE PTR ds:0x1,0x1`